# How to validate a parameter for a class within a method and prevent use if invalid?

Tags: php, api, validation, oop

I am building a small class to handle api requests and I am running into an issue with error handling (I am also a novice at OOP so please with me) I need to restrict or throw an error with any methods in my class that require the user parameter to be set and I also need to samething if token has not been retreived and I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

This is what I have so far...

$user array is set in a config file outside of class like so (empty by default):

```
$user = array(
    'user_email' = '',
    'user_pass' = ''
);
```

Class for handling API (simplified for question)

```
class eventAPI {

    private $user
    private $token

    public function __construct($user) {

        $this->user = $user;

        // if possible assign token when instantiated
        $this->retrieve_token($user);

    }

    private function retreive_token($user) {

        // Check if user parameter has been set
        if($this->validate_user_parameter()) {

            // use credentials to make HTTP request for token 
            $token = 'somerandomtoken';

            // assign token property retreived value
            $this->token = $token;

        } else {

            echo 'User parameter has not been set.' // Not real message just for testing
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function show_all_events() {

        // Check if token has been retreived
        if($this->validate_token_retreived()) {

            // Use token to retreive events list via HTTP request

        } else {

            echo 'API not active. No valid token detected'; // for testing purposes
            return FALSE
        }

    }

    // reduntant code... Can't wrap my head around another way for checking for token.
    public function show_single_event() {

        // Check if token has been retreived
        if($this->validate_token_retreived()) {

            // Use token to retreive events list via HTTP request

        } else {

            echo 'API not active. No valid token detected'; // for testing purposes
            return FALSE
        }
    }

    // This is mostly where I am confused how to solve. 
    private function validate_user_parameter() {

        foreach($this->user as $key => $value) {

            // Remove whitespace from value
            $value = trim($value);

            if(empty($value)) {

                echo 'User credentials have not been set'; // for testing purposes

                return FALSE;

            }
        }

    }

    private function validate_token_retreived() {

        $result = FALSE;

        // Bool value not sure if this is the best way to do this
        if(isset($this->$token)) {
            $result = TRUE;
        }

        return $result;
    }


}
```

First issue: I need to validate the user parameter which is in an array so I can use with a private method to retrieve the token. I chose to use a foreach loop to check each value but it seems a little archaic.

Second Issue: I have a redundant check in place for each public method to check if token is valid. Is there a better way to do this with OOP? I have many methods that require the token.

In short, how can I make sure that once the class is instantiated a public method that will be used by end user will not fire if any validation fails. The user info only needs to be valid once when instantiated and then the token needs to be valid for most remaining methods.

Comment: I would validate only during construction, and immediately fail. That way, you don't need to validate anywhere else.

Comment: You're sending false values but where's trues ?

Comment: @rjdown that's exactly the alternative I am looking for. If validation fails in the constructor, how would I go about making all methods fail after instance has been created. I tried something similar but I couldn't seem to get it to work appropriately.

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ for the event functions. I was using return FALSE to escape the call on the function if validation failed (maybe bad practice?). For the user array. I chose not to put a true value, mainly because of an issue I encountered using the foreach() since i look at each value. If I had it return true on one value lets say just the email was entered but no pass I would get a return of true then a a return of false or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You don't need to pass `$user` parameter to `retreive_token` function. You got it in class scope. Just use `$this->user` in the function to access it. Also you didn't use it in that function, so why u passed it?
- You didn't send `true` in any function.
- There's nothing wrong with `for-each` but you want to check `array_map` too. Atleast you're applying a function to every item in array. It can be usefull. **ps:** seems `for-each` still faster then `array_map`
- Also you would want to check `empty` function on which cases it returns false
- You can use multiple returns in a function. You dont need to set a variable to do that.

**Example**

```
private function validate_token_retreived()
{
    if(isset($this->token))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

- You couldn't use `else` in most cases.

**Example**

```
public function show_all_events()
{
   if($this->validate_token_retreived()) {
       // Use token to retreive events list via HTTP request 
       // and return here

   }

   echo 'API not active. No valid token detected'; // for testing purposes
   return FALSE; // do you really return here? seems you are just generating an output
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the retrieve_token function I need the $user value to make a HTTP call for token. I stripped all the functions of all the guts to focus on the question at hand, sorry for the confusion. Should I send true if function is successful. I was using return false to end function from continuing as a fail safe (not sure if this is the correct way of doing this either) . Lastly, could you explain why you can't use else, I am a little confused what you mean.

Comment: You can. There's nothing wrong with using else. But most stuations its useless to return in function.ex: if (this) {return that} else {return that} is simple equal to if (this) {return that} return that. If the condition return true, than function will stop when it see return keyword in brackets. if not, brackets won't execute.

Comment: Oh and sending false to finish a function is not a good this. just return false if the result is false or something is wrong. dont worry about to stop function. it will stop when it done or when it see a return block.